# Can I use instance variables in stateless session bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javabeans, stateless

I know that stateless bean doesn't maintain conversational state but what I need is just a logger. Should I get logger in every method which is called? If not then where should I initialize it?

Is that's for sure that if I write such code I won't get NullPointerException in some method which uses logger?

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
   logger = Logger.getLogger();
 }
```

Comment: It's not "controversial" but "conversational" state, although that topic might be controversial :)

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! I am really sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'd not want to have a request/session specific logger, right? In that case you could even use a static class member to add the logger and let all bean instances use the same logger.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class which will have the following properties:

1. Static field with the type of the class itself
2. Private constructor to insure that only one instance of this logger
   class is initiated
3. `getInstance()` method which will give the only instance of the class
4. `getLogger()` method to get the logger

Initialize the logger in the constructor of this class and
You can get the logger from the getLogger() method every-time you need to use it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger();
```

If you need Thread specific values take care that the output handler of the Logger writes the Thread name in every line and you should be fine.